# Adding environment variables to Spring's application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, application.properties

I want to run two Amazon S3's SDK information from the `application.properties`, but instead of putting it in the file, I want to add them when running `./mvnw spring-boot:run`. I saw something like this could be done:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--srp.storage.s3.access-key=FOOBARFOOBAR,--srp.storage.s3.secret-key=foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar"
```

I tried running the command above with quotes around the arguments and with/without whitespace between them. Also, I tried leaving blank values in the properties files as well as removing them at all.

```
# srp.storage.s3.access-key=
# srp.storage.s3.secret-key=
```

```
srp.storage.s3.access-key=
srp.storage.s3.secret-key=
```

I have a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties("srp.storage")`. The results of these attempts varied from application failing to start because no property was found by the class, to actually running but taking no effect. The variations of the command that caused the server not to start was not specifying any property in `application.properties` and attempting to run the command with and without quotes and no whitespace. The scenario that it ran but did not take effect was putting whitespace.

I know about running it using the built JAR file, but I want to be able, if possible, to run it like that just to prevent building every time I change something.

Also attempted to specify placeholder as shown here, but again no success. Can I even do what I want using `./mvnw`? Or must it be with a JAR file?

```
srp.storage.s3.access-key=${access-key}
srp.storage.s3.secret-key=${secret-key}
```

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--access-key=FOOBARFOOBAR,--secret-key=foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar"
```

Comment: i think `-D` will fix your problem, if you run it from command line, ex:
`./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=FOOBARFOOBAR  -Dsrp.storage.s3.access-key=something  -D srp.storage.s3.secret-key=whatever`.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't fix. Also, I don't understand what I would be passing to `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments`? The "FOOBARFOOBAR" is one of the keys required by AWS SDK, so it would be passed to "access-key". I did try using this syntax but no luck.

Comment: I saw it while editing, I screwed up when pasting in here. I fixed it.

Comment: Solved using environment variables. That's good enough for me.

Comment: Good luck,.....

Answer (score 0):

Solved using environment variables. That's good enough for me. 
It goes without saying you can choose any name you want for the property in Spring's file and variable, just remember that in Linux environments you must set the variable names all capital letters and use underscore.

In `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or similar, add:

```
export AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY=FOOBARFOOBAR
export AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY=foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar
```

And as shown before, in the `application.properties` file, add;

```
srp.storage.s3.access-key=${AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY}
srp.storage.s3.secret-key=${AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY}
```

And start normally. Much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle and have `bootRun` task available then you can configure the task to read the args passed while running the task.

Add the following to your build file.

```
bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('params')) {
        args project.params.split(",")
    }
}
```

Then you can run the following command.

```
.\gradlew.bat bootRun -Pparams=--demo.prop=commandlinearg
```

I had a field annotated as the following

```
@Value("${demo.prop}")
private String prop;
```